# GroupBy by many different keys

Tags: c#, linq

```
    var expr = Data.Customers
        .GroupBy(c => c.Country, c => c.Name);

    foreach (IGrouping<Countries, string> customerGroup in expr)
    {                
        Trace.WriteLine("Country: " + customerGroup.Key);
        foreach (var item in customerGroup)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Trace.WriteLine("");
    }
```

I wish I got following result:

Country: Italy

Paolo
Marco

Country: USA

James
**Frank**

instead of:

Country: Italy
Paolo
Marco

Country: USA
James
**Frank
Frank**

If it is possible, please make it using standard LINQ syntax.

Comment: You haven't specified your input data, or what this has to do with "many different keys".

Comment: Look at [this example](http://www.arpitkhandelwal.com/2011/12/c-linq-to-objects-using-groupby-with.html), if it works for you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to group by multiple keys you have to use an anonymous type:

```
var expr = Data.Customers 
             .GroupBy(c =>new{c.Country, c.Name});
```

Then you can access `expr.Key.Country` and `expr.Key.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I think you don't need to group by Name

```
var expr = Data.Customers
        .GroupBy(c => c.Country);
```

Comment: A also need to group the sequence by name

Answer (score 0):

```
    var expr = Data.Customers
                    .Select(c => new { c.Country, c.Name})
                    .Distinct()
                    .GroupBy(c => c.Country, c => c.Name);
```

I've found a clumsy solution, but without using LINQ syntax.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. This query really makes no sense (or I don't see it). What is the purpose of grouping into groups of just one element?

Comment: I've already achieved the result. I hopped to filter the customers by their names using the GroupBy operator, because I didn't want to have several similar names like Frank and then I wanted to group the customers by their countries.

Comment: I'd be pleased if somebody told me know how to achive the same result using LINQ syntax.

Comment: I misread your answer and didn't understand your question... What's wrong with using this sintax vs the "standard Linq Syntax"?